# How to print a MySQL table that counts the number of drives per top three drivers?

Tags: mysql, sql

**PROBLEM:**

Consider a table called `drives` with the following columns:

```
drive_id, driver_id, date_time, start_state, end_state
```

Each row is a drive from one state to another on a given date for a given driver.

For the 3 drivers that have done the most drives, write a query that prints a table that counts the number of drives per driver by start_state and end_state.

Output should have columns:

```
start_state, end_state, driver_id, n_drives
```

Below is some code I tried:

```
SELECT
    start_state,
    end_state,
    driver_id,
    COUNT(*) AS n_drives
FROM drives
JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS drive_counts,
        driver_id
    FROM drives
    ORDER BY drive_counts DESC
    LIMIT 3
) AS top_three_drivers USING (driver_id)
GROUP BY start_state, end_state, driver_id;
```

Here is what the table should look like:

```
NY | PA | driver_4 | 1
PA | OH | driver_3 | 2
NY | NY | driver_5 | 2
OH | PA | driver_3 | 5
OH | NY | driver_4 | 1
```

Comment: what's the relation between drive_id and driver_id ?

Comment: I would help if you could share sample data that corresponds to your expected output. That would sure make your question more talkative.

Comment: What does the attempted query return? How does it not output desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your published query is that you are not grouping in the sub query. This results in an implied group by over the whole record set and indeterminate value being returned for driver id. This in turn means that the outer query will only find the driver_id of the indeterminate value returned by the sub query.

Given

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(drive_id int, driver_id int, date_time date, start_state varchar(1), end_state varchar(1));

insert into t values
(1,1,'2019-03-31','a','b'),
(1,1,'2019-03-31','a','b'),
(1,1,'2019-03-31','b','c'),
(1,2,'2019-03-31','a','b'),
(1,2,'2019-03-31','a','b'),
(1,3,'2019-03-31','a','b'),
(1,3,'2019-03-31','a','b'),
(1,4,'2019-03-31','a','b');
```

The sub query

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS drive_counts,
    driver_id
FROM t
ORDER BY drive_counts DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Returns

```
+--------------+-----------+
| drive_counts | driver_id |
+--------------+-----------+
|            8 |         1 |
+--------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Fixing the sub query to group by driver id (and dumping the nasty using clause in favour of a join)

```
SELECT
    start_state,
    end_state,
    t.driver_id,
    COUNT(*) AS n_drives
FROM t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS drive_counts,
        driver_id
    FROM t
    group by driver_id
    ORDER BY drive_counts DESC
    LIMIT 3
) AS top_three_drivers on top_three_drivers.driver_id = t.driver_id
GROUP BY start_state, end_state, t.driver_id
order by t.driver_id,start_state;
```

Results in

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| start_state | end_state | driver_id | n_drives |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| a           | b         |         1 |        2 |
| b           | c         |         1 |        1 |
| a           | b         |         2 |        2 |
| a           | b         |         3 |        2 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is what I would expect. BTW the question is a poor one since it doesn't cater for draws - in this sample driver 2 and 3 have the same number of drives so perhaps driver 4 should also appear.